# crossfilter/dc.js - filtering to show more details

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to display a pie chart, showing sales for various items(eg clothes, shoes, hats), then when a part of the pie chart is clicked, the sales figures for that item, broken down by country will be shown. So, if user clicks, for example, shoes, pie chart will show shoe sales divided by country.
The issue is that I'm trying to create a group with sales for a particular item, but am getting null values.

```
pie.onClick = function(i) {
    var x = i.key;
    console.log("Getting data for "+x);

    var countryDim = cf.dimension(function(d){
        return d.country;
    });
    console.log("countryDim");
    print_filter(countryDim);
    var salesPerItemByCountryGroup = countryDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){
        if(d.item == x){
            return d.sales;
        }
        });
    print_filter(salesPerItemByCountryGroup);
    pie.dimension(countryDim).group(salesPerItemByCountryGroup);
    dc.redrawAll();
};
```

See this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SeamusA/mz9ossr3/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: I took a look at your Fiddle. Why do you need the `reduceSum`?  Don't you just want to show `countryDim.group()` of the corresponding category based on the pie chart click?

Comment: Hi Manual, Thanks for looking,  countryDim.group() will return the number of objects in the data for each country -[{"key":"Mexico","value":3},
 {"key":"USA","value":3},
 {"key":"Canada","value":3} ]. Instead I need something returned like [{"key":"Mexico", value:"100"}, {"key":"Canada", value:"100"}, {"key":"Usa", value:"100"}]   so I can create the pie chart with these values. Also, it could be the case that, for eg country :Mexico and item: hats will have multiple entries in the received data, and that will need to be summed to give a total value of sales for hats in Mexico

Comment: ah, makes sense. Ok, I'll take a closer look and see if I can see why you're getting `[{"key":"USA", "value":null}, ...]`

Comment: Why do you have an onClick handler set on your pie chart? And why, in that handler, do you replace the dimension/group in the pie chat? That's not how Crossfilter or dc.js are supposed to work. Build the dimensions and groups you need ahead of time. dc.js will handle filtering and redrawing.

Comment: Here's a working example that I think is what you are trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/9ju7qvsf/1/

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. I dont have enough space to show two pie charts, so the idea was to use one pie chart, then by clicking on parts of that pie chart, to get more detailed information. So, first show items, then click on an item,eg shoes, to  see sales figures for shoes in each country, then click on a country,eg Mexico, to see sales figures for shoes in each city in Mexico. Here is updated code I was working on before I saw your reply. http://jsfiddle.net/SeamusA/22e0p4z6/1/ . Is it possible to use your code with just one pie chart?

Comment: This is definitely not how dc.js is supposed to work - where is the "cross" in crossfilter now? But it looks like you kind of got it working. You should still create the other group outside the click and just assign it within. And I guess you'll need a "back" or "up" button to make this navigable.

Comment: Unfortunately, i had to do to this way, i would liked to have shown more charts, to use crossfilter and dc.js fully, but was given certain constraints. @gordon, thanks for the tips, will try to do it that way.

Comment: I'm not judging, just commenting that you seem to have found a solution. Creating the group outside is important because otherwise your page will get slower and slower. Crossfilter groups are expensive.